# Convert simple jQuery to plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problem trying to convert this piece of code from jQuery into pure JavaScript.

The script is

```
if($('#item-1').find('#player').length == 1)
{
    innerHTML = "You Won!!!";
} else {
    innerHTML = "You Lose!!!";
}
```

Do I have to use getElementById?

```
if(document.getElementById("#item-1 #player").length == 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use querySelector :

```
//evaluates to true if length > 0
if(document.querySelectorAll('#item-1 #player').length)
{
    innerHTML = "You Won!!!";
} else {
    innerHTML = "You Lose!!!";
}
```

or in 1 line code :

```
var innerHtml = document.querySelectorAll('#item-1 #player').length ? 'You Won!!!' : 'You Lose!!!';
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` will return a single node. `document.querySelectorAll` will return a collection of nodes. The former doesn't have a `length` property.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById` accepts the ID of single element without `#`. You need `querySelector`.

```
document.querySelector('#item-1 #player').length
```

Also, as ID is **unique** there is no need of descendant selector. The ID of the element can directly be used.

```
document.getElementById('player')
```

**Code:**

```
innerHtml = document.getElementById('player') ? 'You won!!!' : 'You lose!!!';
```

More complex:

```
innerHtml = 'You ' + (document.getElementById('player') ? 'won' : 'lose') + '!!!';
```

Comment: "Also, as ID is unique there is no need of descendant selector." actually given the code it's likely that one element may be within the other at different times (it's very easy to move DOM nodes), which would mean that `document.querySelector('#item-1 #player')` would be appropriate for checking state, where `document.getElementById('player')` would not.